# Matlab continuous timer

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out the best approach to this so I appreciate your thoughts. I'm running a model that uses the number of minutes remaining as an input. Let's say it counts down to September 30th. So as of right now there is roughly 21*24*60 = 30,240 minutes remaining. The time remaining should decrease every second. How can I achieve this? Some sort of endless loop? Part of a script? Or a function? Keep in mind this is only one input in my model, and there are many other moving parts. What type do I want...a datetime array? That is what I have been working with so far.

Comment: Are you interested in executing the model every second? Or is that separately controlled and you just want to pass the correct time remaining regardless of when the model is executed? Please provide an example to clarify.

Comment: Yes I will have the model running every second, or turned on I should say, but it will only yield output once a minute. So say it's 10 pm and the sun rises at 6 am, which is the end of my countdown. At this moment there are 480 minutes to sunrise, and the timer will decrease second by second, but I will only capture/store data once per minute. By sunrise, I will have captured 480 data points. Then I turn the model off and wait til sundown to turn it on again.